# VBA Search Textbox and Populate Listbox

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have Userform which i can type the barcode and description of the item in the textbox and it will display result... but in my code i can search only the first column... i want all the column in the sheet to search in the textbox i have 8 columns

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.text = StrConv(Me.TextBox1.text, vbProperCase)
    Dim i As Long
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
      a = Len(Me.TextBox1.text)
      If Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).text, a) = Left(Me.TextBox1.text, a) Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value

      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `if <found in col 1> or <found in col 2> or ... then`.  Also `Left(Me.TextBox1.text, a)` isn't doing anything as `a` is the length of the text.  You can replace it with `Me.TextBox1.text`

Comment: I dont understand please edit on my code thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = StrConv(Me.TextBox1.Text, vbProperCase)
    Dim i, x As Long
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
      a = Len(Me.TextBox1.Text)
      For x = 1 To 8
      If Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, x).Text, a) = Left(Me.TextBox1.Text, a) Then
       Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value
      End If
      Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  I believe I know what you mean, but since your code block is very similar to that shown in the original problem would you be able to specify exactly what changes you've made and how they solve the problem?

Comment: the searching is taking time and also.. i cant able to display the 3rd column

Comment: yah Just  
For x = 1 To 8
      If Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, x).Text, a) = Left(Me.TextBox1.Text, a) Then
to search in 8 columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this code faster...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim myArray, lr, x, i
    Dim DATA As Worksheet
    Set DATA = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = DATA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ListBox1.Clear
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
    myArray = DATA.Range("A2:H" & lr + 1)
    ReDim y(1 To UBound(myArray) * 8, 1 To 8)
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
     a = Len(Me.TextBox1.Text)
     For x = 1 To 8
     If Left(myArray(i, x), a) = Left(TextBox1.Text, a) Then
            rw = rw + 1
            For yy = 1 To 8
                y(rw, yy) = myArray(i, yy)
            Next yy
        End If
        Next
    Next i
    If rw > 0 Then
        ListBox1.List = y()
    End If
End Sub
```

But searching all the columns at once takes time but here's the idea

[click here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xdr8sxdruae2jru/fast_serch.zip/file)

Comment: thank you it can search all the column but the problem is when i search in the textbox it takes time like 10sec ? is there something we can do about this to make it fast

Comment: Change the event
 
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()  to Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
and press Enter AfterUpdate

Comment: It works but why the result showing only if i click the listbox? it should display the result while i type the Char*

Comment: Because the event after typing just press Enter from keyboard and the result will appear